# Comma for thousands separator on a bound WebForms TextBox

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm trying to format a data bound value as below, but I keep getting a space as the thousands separator, i.e. the displayed text is always "12 340.00" when it should be "12,340.00".

What am I missing?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="budgetText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Budget", "{0:#,0.00}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the culture:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="budgetText" 
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:#,0.00}", Bind("Budget")) %>' />
```

or [set the UI culture globally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Comment: It gives me the following error  (The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context)